# Find the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{5^{n} + (-1)^{n}}{n^{3}}\right)(x-2)^{n}$

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, power-series

Find the radius of convergence of the following:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{5^{n} + (-1)^{n}}{n^{3}}\right)(x-2)^{n}$$

My attempt:

I used Ratio Test and managed to get until

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \bigg|\frac{5^{n+1} + (-1)^{n+1}}{5^{n} + (-1)^{n}} \left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{3} (x-2)\bigg|$$

I need to use L'Hopital Rule to get the answer.

Comment: L'Hospital's rule is a counsel of despair. The term $n/(n+1)\to 1$ surely. For the first fraction divide top and bottom to get $(5+(-1)^{n+1}5^{-n})/(1+(-1)^n5^{-n})$. Where to top and bottom here converge?

Answer (score 1):

L'Hospital's rule is not necessary here, one may just write, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\left|\frac{5^{n+1} + (-1)^{n+1}}{5^{n} + (-1)^{n}} \cdot\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{3} (x-2)\right|=5\left|\frac{1 + \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{5^{n+1}}}{1 + \frac{(-1)^{n}}{5^{n}}} \cdot\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{3}} \right|\cdot|x-2| \to \color{red}{5|x-2|}.
$$

Comment: You are using L Hospital Rule for $$\frac{1 + \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{5^{n+1}}}{1+ \frac{(-1)^{n}}{5^{n}}}$$?

Comment: I'm rather using that $\frac{(-1)^{n}}{5^{n}} \to 0$ since $5^n \to \infty.$ Then $$ \frac{1 + \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{5^{n+1}}}{1+ \frac{(-1)^{n}}{5^{n}}} \to \frac{1 +\color{red}{0}}{1 +\color{red}{0}}$$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: My understanding is that $(-1)^{n+1} \rightarrow \infty$ and $5^{n+1} \rightarrow \infty$. Since $\frac {\infty}{\infty}$, it is indeterminate, and you have to use L Hospital Rule?

Comment: In fact, $$\left|\frac{(-1)^{n}}{5^{n}}\right|\le\frac1{5^n} \to 0  $$as $n \to \infty$.  Do you see it?

Comment: Ah I see it: $(-1)^{n+1} \rightarrow 1$, so it is not indeterminate.

Comment: Not really, you have $ \left| \dfrac{a}{b}\right|=\dfrac{|a|}{|b|} $ giving here $\left|\frac{(-1)^n}{5^n}\right|=\dfrac{|(-1)^n|}{|5^n|}=\frac1{5^n}$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{5^n+(-1)^n}{n^3}(x-2)^n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{\{5(x-2)\}^n}{n^3}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{\{(-1)(x-2)\}^n}{n^3}$$

Can you apply Ratio Test separately?

OR

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \bigg|\frac{5^{n+1} + (-1)^{n+1}}{5^{n} + (-1)^{n}} \left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{3} (x-2)\bigg|$$
$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|(x-2)\left(\dfrac1{1+\dfrac1n}\right)^3\cdot\dfrac{5-\left(\dfrac15\right)^n}{1+\left(\dfrac15\right)^n}\right|=|5(x-2)|$$

Answer (score 0):

The root test is better here.

Taking the n-th root,
the only term that matters
is $5^n$,
with an n-th root of $5$.

Therefore,
the radius of convergence is
$\frac15$,
centered at $x=2$.

What happens at the border points
would take more precise analysis.